# One step in proving Kakutani-Krein Theorem (about the closed lattice separating points)

Tags: functional-analysis

This question is about a step in Reed and Simon's functional analysis book, in proving Kakutani-Krein Theorem. (Any closed lattice $\mathcal{L}$ in $C_\mathbb{R}(X)$, where X is compact Hausdorff, which separates points and which contains 1 is all of $C_\mathbb{R}(X)$.)

One statement that appears in the proof is that since $\mathcal{L}$ separates points and contains 1, for any $h\in C_\mathbb{R}(X)$ and for any $x,y\in X$, $\exists f_{xy}\in\mathcal{L}$ such that $f_{xy}(x)=h(x)$ and $f_{xy}(y)=h(y)$.

If $x=y$, this is true because $1\in\mathcal{L}$. If $x\neq y$, since $\mathcal{L}$ separates points, we can find a function taking different values at x and at y. By shifting it using the constant functions, one can make it to take value $h(x)$ at x. However, it is not clear to me how to construct a function $f$ which agrees with $h$ at both x and y, just using the property of separating points.

I'd appreciate it if anyone can give me some hint on constructing such a $f_{xy}$. Sorry in advance if this turns out to be trivial, and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=h(x)$ and $b=h(y)$. If $g(x)\neq g(y)$ then $\phi(t)= (g(t)-g(x))/(g(x)-g(y))$ satisfies $\phi(x)=0$ and $\phi(y)=1$. Then set $f(t)= a+\phi(t)(b-a)$.